# Why am I getting a "server tag not well formed error" on the following code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I know I'm missing something, but my limited experience is hindering me.  Any advice?  Thanks for any help!

Page code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="image1" ImageUrl="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url") %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable("images");
        dt.Columns.Add("url");
        dt.Rows.Add("http://www.boeing.com/assets/images/defense-space/military/p8a/images/P8-A_index.jpg");
        dt.Rows.Add("http://www.tractorbynet.com/forums/attachments/power-trac/258427d1333048884-p-8-replacing-p3c-p-8a_mma_changed_wing_lg.jpg");

        var ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        Repeater1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use single quotes as

```
ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url") %>'
```

Comment: Hey, that worked!  Thanks so much!!  As soon as the timer is up, I'll mark this the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your "" here are getting mix-matched around your URL parameter:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="image1" ImageUrl="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url") %>" />
```

should be:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="image1" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url") %>' />
```

Comment: Hmm.  Let me try that out real quick.  Hmm.  Same error, even after changing the double quotes to single.  Thanks, though!

Comment: Have you tried the other way around? <asp:Image runat="server" ID="image1" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url") %>' />

Comment: Edited my answer, needs to be the other way around, sorry.

Comment: @pinoy_ISF That worked!  I saw Bhavin's answer below, before I saw your comment, but I wanted to let you know that it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @thedixon Thank you!  I sure appreciate the help.